# How to clear the routes when logout in persistent bottom navigation bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this package [Link to the package](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) to build the bottom navigation bar in my Flutter app. The logout button is located at the fifth tab of the bottom navigation bar. When the user tap the logout button, it suppose to clear all the routes and return to to the Login Page.

The problem that I face now is that the route of the fifth tab is cleared when logout button is pressed, but the routes in the leftover 4 tabs is not clear. So when a new user login, all the info of the previous user is exposed to the new user login in.

Does anyone has suggestions regarding my issue here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of your problem

Comment: I have updated my post with code snippet @quoci

Comment: having same problem

Comment: `Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()),
    );`

Comment: use the pushreplacement instead of push

Answer (score 7, accepted):

got solution try this  [source](https://github.com/BilalShahid13/PersistentBottomNavBar/issues/70)

```
   Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                              .pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return const UserLogin();
                              },
                            ),
                            (_) => false,
                          );
```

Comment: The `rootNavigator: true` part was crucial in removing a logged in tab bar when users log out for me. Thanks.